# Procuring both F-1 and B-1 at the same time

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I'm an Indian citizen, and I need to attend a business meeting from 13th of July in the US sponsored by my company. Hence I will require a B-1 visa for 10 days in mid July.

However, soon after the meeting, I'll be moving for studies and hence will need an F-1 visa from 10th of August for staying at an institute in the US for the next few years. The college will be sending me the I-20 this week.

How should I proceed to book slots with the consulate? Will there be any effect on either of the visas? I cannot seem to find information on such a case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the business meeting begin more than 30 days before the beginning of your program of study?

Comment: One can hold different non-immigrant visas simultaneously. You can however only have one status which is the one you enter the USA with, unless you subsequently change status.

Comment: @TheZealot even after you change status, you still have just one status; it's just that you subsequently have a different status from the one you had before the change.

Comment: @phoog updated the question with dates. No it is within 30 days.

Comment: @TheZealot I didn't quite understand the holding two visas and have one status when you enter the USA. Does this mean I should be able get them both and choose B1 when I enter in July and F1 in August?

Comment: Yes, @TheZealot is saying that you can get both visas and use the B-1 visa in July and the F-1 visa in August.  You might also consider whether you can use the F-1 visa in July, since it will be less than 30 days before the start of your program.

Comment: I have a different kind of trouble here. The Consulate dates for both interviews are available only at the end of June and it will be mid-July by which I'll need a B1. I'm anxious about booking two different dates during this period as I'll also need to submit the passport when the interview is complete. Will this cause any major issue at the consulate?

Comment: Here's the update. There is absolutely no problem in procuring both visas and I was unnecessarily nervous about the process. I applied for the slots beforehand and had only a week gap between both interviews. I have also completed the trip on B1 and didn't have any problems whatsoever, except for the immigration officer being confused for a second as he opened the F1 first and I was saying I had a B1. To add to this I had to also get a UK visitor visa for my trip, that went without any problem as well. Visa processing seemed like a breeze if one has proper documents all the way.